Non-conformity of compiler-extensions slipping through the cracks
I would expect the following code to be rejected because zero-sized arrays are not allowed in C++. However, Clang seems to have no problem with it and blatantly accepts it.
template<typename T>
concept c = requires { T{}; };

static_assert(c<int[]>); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope

I understand that some compilers—like Clang and GCC—can actually support zero-sized arrays by means as a compiler-extension. But, is this extended behavior something I should expect the compiler to resort to when the syntax of a constraint is being validated? And, is the answer to this question equally true to substitution failures?
Should the expected behavior of such scenarios be indepedent of the use of the -pedantic flag? Note that Clang accepts this code example while having the -pedantic-errors flag enabled.
Demo

Also note that all 3 of the major compilers have problems with this in one way or another. An example of GCC being non-conforment can be found here. And, an example of MSVC being non-coforment can be be found here.

The discrepancies between these compilers can lead to some really subtle bugs. For example, when using overload-resolution that depends on SFINAE techniques or constraint-checking with concepts, suddenly having a different overload selected when switching between compilers, and without the compiler emitting any kind of warning, is not something you want to run in to.

I suggest reporting these as bugs, if they haven't been reported yet. As I said in my answer, I doubt that they behavior is intended by the developers without -pedantic/-pedantic-errors and it is clearly a bug with either.

The program is ill-formed because T{} is ill-formed with int[] substituted for T.
As a consequence a conforming compiler must emit some diagnostic (whether a warning or an error).
Clang is not doing that, so it is non-conforming.
Obviously the standard has nothing to say about the -pedantic/-pedantic-errors flags, but generally GCC and Clang are non-conforming without them in the sense that they do not diagnose ill-formed programs that make use of an extension if they are only ill-formed due to that extension use.
However, as far as I know, the policy is usually that the extensions should not influence overload resolution, SFINAE and such. So I would say that this is likely unintended here by the compiler authors even if -pedantic/-pedantic-errors is not given.
That is because, if you had for example written static_assert(!c<int[]>); instead, the program would be well-formed according to the standard and it would be a much worse kind of non-conformance in terms of quality-of-implementation if the compiler failed to compile a program that isn't ill-formed or even miscompiled it. So the policy I suggest above is kind of necessary to avoid severe divergence from the standard language.
(Nothing here is C++23-specific by the way. The same answer would apply for C++20 and initializing an array with unknown bounds with an empty initializer list has always been ill-formed.)

"As a consequence a conforming compiler must emit some diagnostic"
But what about IF-NDRs? Can't there be programs that are ill-formed but don't require a diagnostic? And, how do we know if this example program isn't one of them? Which passage in the C++23 standard either confirms or refute this?

"However, as far as I know, the policy is usually that the extensions should not influence overload resolution and such." I understand that there is no mention of compiler-extensions in the C++23 standard. However, it would be nice to have something official to refer to that supports this anecdotal claim.

"... it would be a much worse kind of non-conformance if the compiler failed to compile a program that isn't illformed." I'm not sure if I'm following you on this, as Clang accepting c<int[]> also infers rejecting !c<int[]>. So, how would this be different? Are there different forms of non-conformity? Is this there a mention of this in the C++23 standard?

"Nothing here is C++23-specific by the way." That's true and I don't mind to have the question changed to C++20. However, I am looking for an answer that applies to the latest publication of the C++ standard.

Hi. I understand that there is no mention of compiler-extensions in the C++23 standard. Undefined behavior is exactly the place where to put compiler extensions. Some compiler extensions conflict with the standard - as in this case. My understanding is that "the policy" mentioned in the answer refers to GCC and clang developers general intention, not to the C++ standard wording. Are there different forms of non-conformity? Compilers can do and do what they want. It is easy to characterize, there is "strict conformance", there is implementation-defined, undefined and ill-formed.

@303: The tag for the "latest version of the C++ standard" is just C++. The C++23 tag is for the 2023 version of the C++ standard, which may or may not be the latest standard at the time you're reading this.

@303 "But what about IF-NDRs?": If the standard doesn't explicitly say that no diagnostic is required, then a diagnostic is required for an ill-formed program. "I understand that there is no mention of compiler-extensions in the C++23 standard": That's not completely true. https://eel.is/c++draft/intro#compliance.general-9.sentence-2 clarifies that extensions do not permit the compiler to drop diagnostics where they are otherwise required.

"However, it would be nice to have something official to refer to that supports this anecdotal claim.": I am not sure where to look for that. I can only guess some compiler developer comments in bug reports or such maybe. "Are there different forms of non-conformity?": No, but from a practical perspective not compiling a well-formed program or miscompiling it is worse than failing to diagnose an ill-formed one. Yes, Clang's behavior results in both. What I wanted to say with the quoted phrase is that this is why the policy I suggest is the only one that really makes sense.

@KamilCuk "My understanding is that "the policy" mentioned in the answer refers to GCC and clang developers general intention, not to the C++ standard wording.": Yes, and I am not claiming that I know this to be the developers' intention. I can't point to anything definitive stating such a policy. But from my experience this is how they handle extensions.

IFNDR is for cases that are bad but are inordinately difficult, or potentially impossible, to feasibly diagnose. This is a very easy case to diagnose, and has an explicit, clear rule for it.
